# Is using 'If' in an excel formula bad for performance?

Tags: excel

I am by no means an excel or VBA programmer. I am looking at an excel file for work, and am wondering something about one of the formulas. The programmer added this formula into one of the cells.

`=IF(F2<>"",(D2/((AVERAGE(F2:G2)*$R$21)+1)),D2)`

What I am wondering is if this `If` statement is volatile. That is, is the `If` statement always listening for changes throughout the workbook, and does this have a negative effect on performance?

Comment: Performance is a relative concept. `IF` is going to be in the top 10 most used formulas in how many millions of spreadsheets across the world ? Can you rewrite that formula without the `IF` statement ?

Comment: no http://beatexcel.com/volatile-functions-excel/. I would actually expect the if function version to be a bit faster than the version without if `=D2/(AVERAGE(F2:G2)*$R$21*(F2<>"")+1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `If` statement do not have a a negative effect on perfomance. In fact it depends on the complexity of logical text used in your function. In the situations described above, you probably would not have any problem.

Comment: Thanks for your first answer on Stack Overflow. Do you have a reference you can cite, or a link you can provide to support your answer?

Answer (score 1):

The `If`statement is fine to use as it is probably a reasonable size data and Excel calculates formulas quickly. If the data changes regarding the `If` statement, it will quickly recalculate it.

Answer (score -1):

Performance is not a concern here -- <s>in fact, *every* formula in an Excel workbook is recalculated any time a cell on *any* worksheet is changed, unless you change the calculation mode to "Manual" (see the Formulas tab). This only tends to be a problem, performance-wise, in especially complicated workbooks, with lots of lookups, sumifs/countifs, and especially array formulas. It's only worth thinking about once you actually have to wait for the workbook to recalculate before you can do anything. Changing the calculation mode to manual can itself be a problem because it sets you up to forget to manually run the calculations.</s>

Edit: As @chrisneilsen notes, my statement above is incorrect. See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx) for more information.

Comment: This is not true.  A formula recalculates when one or more of the cells it relies upon changes (exception: volatile function such as INDIRECT recalculate on every recalculation)

Comment: So if I had a large excel file with lots of data, would using this `If` statement in the long run be more cumbersome than having a Macro that only reacts when it is called?

Comment: Ah, yup, @chrisneilsen you're right. There is in fact a dependency chain I didn't know about. I was thinking about how rand() and indirect() always recalculates. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: @JasonChen, no don't go the macro route. "If" is pretty basic and self-documenting. You'd have to put that same conditional logic in the macro anyway, and it'd be more opaque because you would have to open that VBA window to see it.